# My stored procedure cannot show any record in application

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use this stored procedure in my application to fetch record but there is no record fetch from db using this SP.Give message that no Record found

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_RptDailySummaryPTCLBillsCollection_Result]
(
    @DateFrom DATETIME,
    @DatTo DATETIME,
    @SubOfficeID VARCHAR(200),
    @GroupId INT,
    @ClerkName VARCHAR(200),
    @Type VARCHAR(200)
)
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @AgencyTable TABLE (
         GpoId INT
       , OfcId INT
       , Total_Bills BIGINT
       , Total_Amount BIGINT
    ) --Bill_Value BIGINT, Commission BIGINT,

    --SET @DatTo = convert(datetime, convert(Varchar(12), @DatTo, 109) + ' 23:59:59PM')

    -- Billing Summary By GPO Name
    INSERT @AgencyTable (GpoId, OfcId, Total_Bills, Total_Amount) --Bill_Value, Commission,
    SELECT
          Bil.GroupId
        , Bil.SubOfficeId
        , ISNULL(COUNT(Bil.ConsumerNumber), 0) --AS Total_Bills, 
            -- ,ISNULL(SUM(Bil.C_Amount),0) --AS Bill_Value, 
            --,ISNULL(SUM(Bil.Commission),0) --AS Commission, 
        , ISNULL(SUM(Bil.C_Amount), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(Bil.Commission), 0) --AS Total_Amount
    FROM BillTxnSO AS Bil
    INNER JOIN pp_offices ofc ON Bil.GroupId = ofc.Group_Id AND Bil.SubOfficeId = ofc.OfficeCode
    WHERE Bil.GroupId = @GroupId
    AND TransDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DatTo
    GROUP BY Bil.GroupId, Bil.SubOfficeId

    --select * from @AgencyTable

    SELECT
         ofc.OfficeName AS SubOffice
       , ofc.Group_ID AS GroupID
       , ISNULL(gpo.Total_Bills, 0) AS NoOfBills
       , ISNULL(gpo.Total_Amount, 0) AS Amount  -- isnull(gpo.Bill_Value,0)as Bill_Value , isnull(gpo.Commission,0) as Commission, 
    FROM @AgencyTable gpo
    INNER JOIN pp_offices ofc ON ofc.Group_ID = gpo.GpoId AND gpo.OfcId = ofc.OfficeCode
    ORDER BY ofc.OfficeName

END
```

Comment: If you run that procedure in Sql Server Management Studio did you get results? If yes, then the problem is in your C# code and you should add it to your question

Comment: There is no question here, there is only code.

Answer (score 0):

"Give message that no record found"

Use @@ROWCOUNT

```
IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)BEGIN
   Select 'No record found'
   return
END
```